# Why isn't my dropdown appearing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/r2zmxzzd/

As you can see, the dropdown in the top menu "Alumni" is working but the dropdown in the lower menu i.e. "About UET" is not working.

I've been staring at the code for more than 2 hours but still can't get that damn dropdown to appear. I've tried inspecting the elements. The dropdown appears in the DOM as active but still doesn't show up.

Here is the code of the dropdown

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown primaryNavItem">
        <a href="#" class="primaryNavLink dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About UET <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Historic Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Vision &amp; Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Development Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Core Team Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">UET Progress Report 2015</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Student Teacher Ratio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Faculty Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Budget</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">External Linkages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">International Funding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Spin off companies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Progress Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Site map</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="primaryNavDropDownLink">Contacts List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone please tell me why the lower dropdown isn't appearing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say just take the code available on bootstrap website and add your custom elements piece by piece and see where it fails

Comment: I've even tried removing all of my custom css and it still doesn't work on the lower dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 135px;
}
```

and the dropdown is behind. Remove overflow:hidden

Answer (score 3):

You have to use:

```
header {
overflow: visible;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `<header>` has an `overflow: hidden` css property. That's causing the dropdown to be clipped out of view.

Remove `overflow: hidden` from your header: https://jsfiddle.net/r2zmxzzd/1/

Answer (score 3):

Hi your dropdown is working fine but you have to change css on headersee screenshot  [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using an a tag:

```
<a href="#" class="primaryNavLink dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About UET <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Should be:

```
<button type="button" class="primaryNavLink dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About UET <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

And then style as appropriate

Comment: Oka, the button was only part of the deal. The real problem was overflow hidden.